# Loudspeaker announcement to evacuate due to bomb threat

Tags: society, humans

This is a question about protocol/crowd control/building management.

Let's say you're at a crowded building, like a sports game or rock concert. The management running the building has found out about a bomb threat and wants to tell everyone to evacuate the building.

What message do they give over the loudspeakers?

I'm imagining there is a delicate balance of wanting to convey that it's important that people leave, while also not wanting people to panic.

Comment: You know, there are already [some guides](https://www.cisa.gov/publication/evacuation-planning-guides) written by governments and available to the public which address this issue. This is off the first link in a google search I just did on the topic.

Comment: Tim B II thank you; I did search on google before asking, but I guess I didn't know the right terms to search for.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link you provided seems to just provide lots of questions, but no examples or advice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The usual protocol is to trigger the fire alarms which should move people outside without triggering any undue concern over why they are being sent outside.  The floor wardens are trained to get everyone out of the building as quickly as possible and to then check in with the main coordinators to confirm evacuation of everyone was successful.

We had multiple bomb threats and were evacuated in this fashion.   Turns out the bomb threat was called in to the security desk by the boyfriend of an employee who wanted to talk to her in the parking lot (multiple times till he was caught).

Comment: The example you give happens when one takes the term "sex bomb" too literally...

Comment: It actually happened... I don't remember if we ever heard what kind of punishment the fellow got.  We had several evacuations before they got him though.  I think this was just before the random shootings started with the two guys here in DC...